# how $2x=x$ , related to differential calculus

Tags: calculus, recreational-mathematics, fake-proofs

can anybody please tell me what's happening here ?

$$1^2=1$$

$$2^2=2+2$$

$$3^2=3+3+3$$

$$x^2 = x+x+\cdots+x \mbox{  ($x$ times)}$$

differentiating both the sides
  $$2x = 1 + 1 + \cdots+1 \mbox{  ($x$ times)}$$

thank u

Comment: Well, by that reasoning, you could also, $$x=\sum_{k=1}^x 1$$ differentiate both sides and get $$1=\sum_{k=1}^x 0 = 0. $$ This issue here is that differentiating involves the $\sum$ itself and not just the variables being added. It is just like when we are asked to differentiate $$f(x):=\int_0^{x^2} y^7 dy$$ with respect to $x$. Shouldn't the summation limits play just as much a role as the integrand?

Comment: $$\bigg(\sum_1^xx\bigg)'=\sum_1^xx'+\sum_1^{x'}x=\sum_1^x1+\sum_1^1x=x+x+2x.$$

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting $$x^2 = x+x+\cdots+x \mbox{  ($x$ times)}$$ then $x$ is a constant no not a variable. So, differentiating both side you will get $0=0$ which is true.

Comment: $$g(x)=x^2 ,domain=\mathbb{R}$$but  in$g(x)=x+x+x+...x $ can you mean g(-1.3) ? or even g(2.76) =?